# ¿Cómo reorganizar dos columnas en base a los datos que contienen?

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con dos columnas diferentes:

```
       dataframe:       
                    min         max
                    480         900
                    100         700
                    800         200
                    300         100
```

Y me gustaría que los valores mínimos de las dos columnas estuvieran en la columna de min y los valores máximos en la de max. Estoy intentando organizarlo con la función if pero no tengo el output que necesito. ¿Cómo podría solucionarlo?
Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Acabo de llegar a la manera de solucionar el problema

Si el valor mínimo es mayor que el máximo crea una nueva columna en la cual donde se cumple pone los valores mínimo y donde no pone los valores máximos

```
 data_frame$min_customizado<-ifelse(data_frame$min > data_frame$max,data_frame$max,data_frame$min)
```

Por el contrario,si el valor máximo es menor al valor mínimo crea una nueva columna en la que pone donde se cumple los valores máximos y donde no, pone los valores mínimos

```
  data_frame$max_customizado<-ifelse(data_frame$min< data_frame$max,data_frame$max,data_frame$min)
```